# Void pointer from class A to method from class B

Tags: c++, function, pointers, methods, member

I need to know if it is possible to 'convert' 
a method from one class to a member-variable of an other class
so i can call this method (from e.g. foo) from the other class (e.g. from bar)

should look like

```
void bar::setFunction( void(*f)())
{
    /*bar::*/func = f; // func <= void (*func)();
}

int main()
{
    foo myclass;
    bar myotherclass;

    bar.setFunction( &myotherclass.dosth);
}
```

Comment: At least `&myotherclass::dosth` should be `&bar::dosth`

Comment: u are right, sorry for my fail

Comment: Check this query, to find out if any of the posts are ansering your  questions: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D%22member+function+pointer%22

Comment: Also check [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind), which are purposed to serve exactly what you need.

Comment: If you solve your problem, it's perfectly OK, to post your solution as an answer (did this for you now).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my Problem:

```
typedef std::function<void()> Func;

class bar
{
public:
    void setFunction( std::function<void()> f ) {
        func = f;
    }
    void call()
    {
        func();
    }
private:
    Func func;
};

class foo
{
public :
    static void dosth()
    {
        std::cout << "hallo" << std::endl;
    }
};



int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    foo myclass;
    bar myotherclass;
    Func fd = &myclass.dosth;
    myotherclass.setFunction( fd );
    myotherclass.call(); // this calls the foo method dosth -> "hallo"
    _sleep( 600 );
}
```